# Bower install error, "status code of git: 127"

Tags: bower

I'm using Bower on Windows 8, and I get an error whenever I try to install a package. In this case, I'm trying to install Twitter Bootstrap. So I run...

```
bower install bootstrap
```

... I get this error...

```
bower cloning git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git
bower cached git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git
bower fetching bootstrap
bower error status code of git: 127

There were errors, here's a summary of them:
- bootstrap status code of git: 127
CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm using Git version 1.7.9.mysgit.0 (insalled via [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/)).

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

To further isolate this issue, I have run this command successfully on Cloud9 IDE

Comment: is it on the PATH (git)?

Comment: @gustavohenke Yes, I opted to add Git to the PATH when installing and running `git --version` returns the version number as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to make `bower cache-clean` and then `bower install bootstrap`, worked here for a Windows Server 2008.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct working on the assumption that it works (I've since removed Windows). Thanks for your answer

Comment: The commands must to be executed from a git bash console, otherwise it won't work.